# How these transactions cause deadlock?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, database-deadlocks

I've 2 types of transactions:
Type 1 includes the following Sqls:

```
UPDATE userdb_ingest_report SET start_time='%s', end_time='%s', is_csv_ingest=%d, success=%d, failed=%d WHERE clientid='%s' AND filename='%s' AND network_id=%d AND data_provider_id=%d;\n
    or
INSERT INTO userdb_ingest_report(clientid, filename, network_id, data_provider_id, start_time, end_time, is_csv_ingest, success, failed) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, %d, '%s', '%s', %d, %d, %d);\n"
    and 
DELETE FROM userdb_ingest_report WHERE clientid<>'%s' AND filename='%s' AND network_id=%d AND data_provider_id=%d;\n
```

Type 2 includes the following Sqls:

```
UPDATE userdb_ingest_report SET start_time=LEAST(%s, start_time), end_time=GREATEST(%s, end_time), is_csv_ingest=%d, success=success+%d, failed=failed+%d WHERE clientid='%s' AND filename='%s' AND network_id='%d' AND data_provider_id='%d'"
    or
INSERT INTO userdb_ingest_report(clientid, filename, network_id, data_provider_id, start_time, end_time, is_csv_ingest, success, failed) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, %d, '%s', '%s', %d, %d, %d);\n
```

There may be 1 instance of type1 and 1-6 instances of type2 running concurrently. Sometimes I'll get the deadlock failure:

```
Update table userdb_ingest_report error. Sql:UPDATE userdb_ingest_report SET start_time=LEAST(20170622134845, start_time), end_time=GREATEST(20170622134846, end_time), is_csv_ingest=1, success=success+184, failed=failed+0 WHERE clientid='clienta' AND filename='file1' AND network_id='48804' AND data_provider_id='386123', Error:Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
or
Insert table userdb_ingest_report error. Sql:INSERT INTO userdb_ingest_report(clientid, filename, network_id, data_provider_id, start_time, end_time, is_csv_ingest, success, failed) VALUES ('clientb', 'fileb', 385316, 385316, '20170622140908', '20170622140922', 1, 372521, 0); , Error:Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

and this is the schema of this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `userdb_ingest_report` (
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `network_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `data_provider_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `is_csv_ingest` smallint(1) NOT NULL,
  `success` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `failed` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `clientid` char(30) DEFAULT '',
  KEY `network_data_provider_clientid_idx` (`network_id`,`data_provider_id`,`clientid`,`filename`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I use show innodb status in mysql, I got the following messages about the last deadlock information:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
170622 21:15:22
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3F427F4B, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 30 lock struct(s), heap size 6960, 41 row lock(s), undo log entries 14
MySQL thread id 43053224, OS thread handle 0x2b8f80ffe940, query id 1158507552 10.1.10.42 backend_new update
INSERT INTO userdb_ingest_report(clientid, filename, network_id, data_provider_id, start_time, end_time, is_csv_ingest, success, failed) VALUES ('auingest03.fwmrm.net_1', '/mnt/sftponly/381963/files/audience/ingest/pending/visitor_attr_381963_20170622145737.csv.gz', 0, 381963, '20170622211520', '20170622211522', 1, 18203, 0)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1026 page no 711706 n bits 176 index `network_data_provider_clientid_idx` of table `fwmrm_stats`.`userdb_ingest_report` trx id 3F427F4B lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 16 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 1: len 8; hex 800000000005d457; asc        W;;
 2: len 30; hex 202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020; asc                               ;;
 3: len 30; hex 2f6d6e742f736674706f6e6c792f3338323033392f66696c65732f617564; asc /mnt/sftponly/382039/files/aud; (total 92 bytes);
 4: len 6; hex 00000c420d62; asc    B b;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3F427F4C, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 500
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
28 lock struct(s), heap size 6960, 38 row lock(s), undo log entries 13
MySQL thread id 43053207, OS thread handle 0x2b8f80bee940, query id 1158507553 10.1.10.41 backend_new update
INSERT INTO userdb_ingest_report(clientid, filename, network_id, data_provider_id, start_time, end_time, is_csv_ingest, success, failed) VALUES ('auingest02.fwmrm.net_1', '/mnt/sftponly/381963/files/audience/ingest/pending/visitor_attr_381963_20170622145737.csv.gz', 0, 381963, '20170622211520', '20170622211522', 1, 36103, 0)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1026 page no 711706 n bits 176 index `network_data_provider_clientid_idx` of table `fwmrm_stats`.`userdb_ingest_report` trx id 3F427F4C lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 16 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 1: len 8; hex 800000000005d457; asc        W;;
 2: len 30; hex 202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020; asc                               ;;
 3: len 30; hex 2f6d6e742f736674706f6e6c792f3338323033392f66696c65732f617564; asc /mnt/sftponly/382039/files/aud; (total 92 bytes);
 4: len 6; hex 00000c420d62; asc    B b;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1026 page no 711706 n bits 176 index `network_data_provider_clientid_idx` of table `fwmrm_stats`.`userdb_ingest_report` trx id 3F427F4C lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 16 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 1: len 8; hex 800000000005d457; asc        W;;
 2: len 30; hex 202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020; asc                               ;;
 3: len 30; hex 2f6d6e742f736674706f6e6c792f3338323033392f66696c65732f617564; asc /mnt/sftponly/382039/files/aud; (total 92 bytes);
 4: len 6; hex 00000c420d62; asc    B b;;
```

so how would this happen, and how can I solve this deadlock?

Comment: many deadlocks can be removed by having the appropriate indexes...

Comment: MySQL locking mechanism is not entirely row based. The situation here is that both rows are on the same page, with the row lock escalated to page lock, this  overlap now locked each others required records. This can be prevented by locking the table (slows down transactions), or maybe a select for update in which you first try to acquire the lock.

Comment: thank you @NorbertvanNobelen. So what should I put into the where clause in the "select for update". And If I use select for update, will it cause deadlock with another "insert into" because they'll both require the same lock page?

Comment: I am going to need some more code from you to answer that a bit better: The short version of your working code: Can you add that?

Comment: Hi @NorbertvanNobelen I'm using Mysql and the version is 5.5.37

Comment: Ok, at least upgrade. 5.5 is a bit old now. Without your real code however it is hard to avoid the issue.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen what do you mean by "real code"?

Comment: You posted the troublesome statements, but what code is wrapping those statements and setting the transaction boundaries (ie: The real code running these statements)